# Unexpected end of stream React Native with Laravel

Tags: php, laravel, react-native, download, expo

I'm using [Expo FileSystem API](https://docs.expo.dev/versions/latest/sdk/filesystem/) to download files from URLs.

This is a sample code:

```js
const downloadMedia = async (filename: string) => {
        const downloadResumable = FileSystem.createDownloadResumable(
            `http://192.168.1.99/api/media/${filename}/download`,
            await makeDownloadPath(filename),
            {
                headers: {
                    Authorization: "Bearer xxx",
                },
            },
            progress => {
                console.log(`Downloading... Progress`, progress);
            }
        );

        const download = await downloadResumable.downloadAsync();
        
        console.log("Download finished", download);
    };
```

It works perfectly with any of the URLs provided here: [Example Videos](https://gist.github.com/jsturgis/3b19447b304616f18657), no matter the size. However, when I try to download files from my local Laravel backend using Laravel Sail (docker), that has a route like this:

```php
return Storage::download($media->path);
```

React native keeps throwing **`"Unexpected end of stream"` error**.

If I keep trying to download several times, sometimes it can finish the download. If the file is very small: 500kb <, it almost always works fines.

Here I have an example with a file larger then 2MB:
[image]

> I had to press the download button more than 5 times so the download could finish properly.

The issue doesn't occur in the browser, Postman and Node with axios. I tried changing Laravel disk storage and a different Android emulator, the issue still remained in React Native.